# Slick grid column summation data not getting refresh while scroll

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am using Slick.grid.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSQUy.png)
Issue when I update column(A) and scroll page to check other column(F) value which is calculating using column A, Column F Summation value not getting changed.
(We have written logic if value change in Column(A) using formula other column(F) value will be changed)
When I refresh page value updated.
Those columns are visible for those column summation data showing Correct.
But while scrolling right side column data is not getting refresh while updating cell.
Below Code used to refresh Grid.
function invalidate() {updateRowCount();invalidateAllRows();render();
}

Comment: Can you please provide more detail, there's not enough info to help you. Is that Grouping? What is your code, which plugin are you using? You can refresh data in the grid by calling `grid.invalidate()` which will invalidate all fields (consider them as dirty) and will re-render all fields.

Comment: Grouping is used  below code to refresh grid...............function refresh() {
            for (var i = grids.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                grids[i].invalidate();
            }
        }

        function refreshRow(row) {
            var rowId = dataview.getRowById(row[itemIdField]);
            for (var i = 0, j = grids.length; i < j; i++) {
                grids[i].invalidate();
                grids[i].invalidateRow(rowId);
                grids[i].render();
            }
            return this;
        }

Comment: Please don't put code like that in a comment, which is hard to read, instead go and update your question and click on the add code button to format it properly.